# Probability between two numbers chosen from 1 to 30.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that you choose an odd number or a multiple of six?

The same number can be chosen twice.

I was stuck on this problem earlier in class, and my teacher said the answer was 2/3, but I am convinced that would be the answer if only one integer was chosen. Could you work this out and show me how to solve this?

Comment: Of the integers $\{ 1, 2, ..., 29, 30 \}$ how many are odd or multiples of $6$?

Comment: You choose 2 numers from 1 to 30? Your question is what is the probability that one number is either an odd number or a multiple of 6?

Comment: The question is asking if a single number is chosen from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 30\}$, what is the probability that the number is odd or a multiple of six?  Try working out the details, then show us your solution so that we can check it.

Comment: Ok, so there is an issue in semantics here. My teacher makes her own tests, and this one just didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Count the odd numbers less than 30, call it $a$
>
> Count the multiples of 6 less than 30, call it $b$
>
> Then count the odd numbers which are multiples of 6 and are less than 30, call it $c$
>
> Your probability will be $\frac{a}{30} + \frac{b}{30} -\frac{c}{30}$
>
> You get it?